# Google Maps API: Directions with Custom Routes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to do the following, but I don't know if it is possible, and in case it is, how to implement it.

Having a set of polylines (which would represent routes) already defined, I want the user to be able to select two points (from and to) and present him with the shortest polyline/route from the set, which he/she would then use to go from point A to point B.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: If I gave an answer that works for you, can you accept it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Google Maps API [Geometry Library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html#Distance) to compute the length of each route, and then select the one that is shortest.